# What is the minimum number of pieces needed in a chess set to account for all possible promoted pieces?

Tags: pawn-promotion, pieces, mathematics, chess-set

How many pieces would be needed in a chess set where all possibilities for promoted pieces are included if pawns are no longer used after they promote?

Comment: I was playing a game on my phone called "Really Bad Chess" the other day and would love to have this set IRL :) Probably doesn't fit in a reasonable box really nicely though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's count.

#### Starting set

- 2 rooks
- 2 bishops
- 2 knights
- 1 queen
- 1 king
- (8 pawns)

#### Max promotions

- 8 rooks
- 8 bishops
- 8 knights
- 8 queens

#### Total

In total you would need 40 pieces and 8 pawns for each color, so 96 units for black and white together.

Edited to bullet format to "look" better.

Comment: Yes so 96 total pieces for white and black when including pawns as pieces.

Comment: No, just 64, right? Because 8 white and 8 black rooks, 8 white and 8 black bishops, 8 white and 8 black knights, and 8 white and 8 black queens. 8*8 = 64. Or did I misinterpret your question?

Comment: 8 rooks or 8 bishops or 8 knights or 8 queens (for one side) so for both sides are 64, each promotion yields only one piece. But in practical games it is hard to promote all 8 pawns for each sides.

Comment: @SorinSolberg You need to add the starting set too (i.e. you need 10 rooks, 9 queens, etc.)

Comment: Oh of course... Okay I see.